# How to check for connectivity with server using javaScript from native Android 2.1 browser?

Tags: jquery, android, web-services, connection, getjson

I am building a web application that needs to be working seamless when being online or off line. For this need to be able to **check my connection with the server**.

The main devices that are to be supported are iphone3+4, ipad, a netbook with chrome and android 2.1+.

The `navigator.onLine` is not exactly what I am looking for. This is unreliable and only checks if you have connectivity, not if you are connected to a specific server.

I tried `jQuery.getJSON` to connect to a ping web-service on my server. This works fine in chrome on the netbook but the native android browser returns null. Ipod touch doesn't do anything at all.

I could use some help with this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It after all had to do with the 'same origin policy' (see comments).
This was **resolved by using JSONP**.

The strange thing is that it looks like I am dealing with the same domain, but oke here the code...

CLIENT-SIDE:
`jQuery.getJSON("url?callback=?", function(data) {
  //Do something
});`

SERVER-SIDE:
`@RequestMapping(value="url", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public void ping(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException {
        String output = request.getParameter("callback") + "({0:1});";
        response.setContentType("text/javascript");
        response.getWriter().write(output);
    }`

Answer (score 5):

I don't exactly understand your situation but it sounds like you should use ...

```
$.ajax({
 url: "test.html",
 cache: false,
 async : false,
 error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // some error code.
        },
 success: function(html){
          // do something.
        }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

**async : false** is to "block" the request, using **test.html** or any other simple file (basically we're just trying to connect.) You could use the **timeout** to set some short time period.

Then see if you get get an **error** or **success** ...

> **error(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)**
>
> A function to be called if the request
>   fails. The function is passed three
>   arguments: The XMLHttpRequest object,
>   a string describing the type of error
>   that occurred and an optional
>   exception object, if one occurred.
>   Possible values for the second
>   argument (besides null) are "timeout",
>   "error", "notmodified" and
>   "parsererror". This is an Ajax
>   Event.This handler is not called for
>   JSONP requests, because they do not
>   use an XMLHttpRequest.

If there is an error, fire some function to handle that, if you get the file back you are good to go.

Comment: Hi Justin... thanks for the quick response.
Unfortunately this works "fine in chrome" as did jQuery.getJSON as well, but "not in de native android browser". The android browser executes both the success and error handler.

Comment: How about then checking for the response ... make the page have like one line  ... "true" or "1" ... then test to see if the **html** returned is == "true" or "1" or whatever?

Comment: Again works fine in chrome, but not in Android's (2.1) native browser. It just returns null. It doesn't even seem to reach the server when I do the `jQuery.ajax` or `jQuery.getJSON` request from the phone. I checked this by logging a debug message on the server. For a moment I thought it might had to do with the 'same origin policy' (http://tinyurl.com/nssvq) but after reading the article I knew that could not be possible.

Comment: Strange. I've made a pretty complex web app that worked just fine in 2.1 myself ... do you have a bit more code you could show / a page that is accessible? I have a 2.1 device actually.

Comment: Don't have an up to date online version so
I've created a temp email to be able to post some code.
Have a look at justinj.mailinator.com

I have been running this code on a Samsung Galaxy 2.1

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using `$.getJSON` in a web app. It works well from many browsers except on Android. In fact, my app is supposed to work offline and then I use a manifest where the JSON file is declared as CACHE. For the initial load, it works well but for the next pages load the app is blocked when loading the JSON file.

I suspect that the offline cache is perceived as another origin than the initial server and the process is blocked.

Hope it helps